# Do something when a file is changed

Tags: automation, make

When I write a LaTeX document, I find myself to press F6 in my editor to compile often. Or when I use SASS, I often type `make` to convert my `.scss` into `.css`.

Now I would like to let the machine do the dirty work and run `make` or something else every time a given file change.

So far I kept a terminal window open and pressed arrow-up and return. Or I used `watch make`, but that seems like an odd solution.

Is there a nice way on Linux to do something when a given file changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `inotifywait`, part of [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).  There are some examples of how to use it on the project's site but a simple approach is,

```
while true; do inotifywait code.cpp -e modify; make; done
```

the key part of which is,

```
inotifywait code.cpp -e modify
```

That command will wait until `code.cpp` is modified then exit.  Put in the infinite loop and followed with `make` causes it to constantly rebuild after every modification.

Besides waiting on modify, you can wait on creation, deletion, access, opening, closing, and more.  I highly recommend looking at the [project examples](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#wiki-info) and [inotifywait man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for some other ideas on how it can be used.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), a cron-like package that responds to filesystem events, instead of time events. The package consists of a daemon (`incrond`) and a table manipulator (`incrontab`), analogous to the well-known `crond`/`crontab` pair of cron.

With incron, you could easily arrange to run `make` whenever particular files and/or directories are modified.

Comment: That seems a little overkill on the one hand, but on the other it is just the right tool. I'll have to check it out, maybe I can enable and disable it for each programming session.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `watch make`, how about `watch ls`?  Then just `make` when the timestamp changes.

Comment: Well, make already checks the timestamps, so it is rather pointless to check the time and then let make check the time again.

Comment: Right but running make is more expensive than running ls.

Comment: And if my makefile is just two lines for that single `.tex`? Do you think that would be worth writing an `ls` parser?